# How to implement mysql "where ? is null " in SpringJDBCTemplate

Tags: mysql, spring-jdbc

I Want to implement a sql as follows in SpringJDBC

> SELECT note from item WHERE sku = :sku AND make = :make

But the query can't find the record actually exist when make is a null property.
After debug,I found out there is a difference between " **make = null** " and " **make is null** " in MYSQL. But there is no API i can find which is suited for that situation in SpringJDBC. Any clues for that or must in static sql?

Comment: put your sku = :sku and make - :make in if condition.Like if (sku is not null), just the append the string with and condition

Comment: @Chinna_82 Of course we can using sql statements combine with java like 
"SELECT note from item WHERE sku = :sku AND "+(make==null?"make is null":" make = \""+make+"\"" or simply using two sql statements judged by make conditions.But i'd prefer a original function or parameter to solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public Item findBySkuAndMake(String sku, String make) {
  Item item = null;

  try {
    String sql = "SELECT note FROM item WHERE sku = :sku AND make = :make";
    SqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource()  
        .addValue("sku", sku)
        .addValue("make", make);

    item = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, parameters, new ItemRowMapper());
  } catch (DataAccessExceptione) {
    System.err.printf("Something went wrong while trying to search inside ITEM; this is why: %s%n", e);
  }
  // Then read getNote() ...or just return it (and change the method's return type)
  return item; 
}

// This is up to you, I don't know what's inside *Item*
private static class ItemRowMapper implements RowMapper<Item> {
  @Override
  public Item mapRow(ResultSet resultSet, int i) throws SQLException {
    return new Item(resultSet.getString("note"), resultSet.getString("sku"),
        resultSet.getString("make");
  }
}
```

If you need to make one (or more) field(s) conditional, just add an `if` clause in the SQL query and exclude it (or them) from `SqlParameterSource`.

Comment: That's a nice idea to try fix this null tricks。I tried your code under spring 4.0.0.RELEASE。There are two thing you might be mistaken or the version are different. **1.**the function of namedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(sql,parameters,new ItemRowMapper()) return only List type. **2.**That function didn't cause exception when the parameter is null.

Comment: Yes, you are right, it should be `queryForObject` instead of just `query`; I fixed it in the example. 'null` value parameters won't cause any exception, that's a valid case.